# Setting startup script in PyCharm debugger console

Tags: python, pycharm

In PyCharm, it is possible to set a script that runs upon opening a new console (through Settings -> 'Build, Execution, Deployment' -> Console -> Python Console -> Starting script).

Is there a way to similarly apply a startup script to the debugger console? I find myself importing the same packages over and over again, each time I run the code.

Answer (score 4):

When you run `Python Console` inside PyCharm, it executes custom PyCharm script at `<PYCHARM_PATH>/plugins/python/helpers/pydev/pydevconsole.py`.

On the other hand, when you run `PyCharm Debug Console` while debugging, it executes  custom PyCharm script at `<PYCHARM_PATH>/Plugins/python/helpers/pydev/pydevd.py` with command line parameter `--file` set to script you are debugging.

You can modify `pydevd.py` file if you want ([Apache 2 license](https://blog.jetbrains.com/pycharm/2017/09/pycharm-community-edition-and-professional-edition-explained-licenses-and-more/)), but the easier approach would be to create startup script in which you import modules you need, functions and such and import **ALL** while inside *PyCharm Debug Console*. This would reduce all your imports to one.

*Walkthrough:*

Let's create 2 files:

- `main.py` - Our main script which we will debug
- `startup.py` - Modules, functions or something else that we would like to import.

`main.py` content:

```py
sentence = 'Hello Debugger'


def replace_spaces_with_hyphens(s):
    return s.replace(' ', '-')


replace_spaces_with_hyphens(sentence) # <- PLACE BREAKPOINT!
```

When breakpoint is hit, this is what we have inside scope:

[image: Stack]

If you always find yourself importing some modules and creating some functions, you can define all that inside `startup.py` script and import everything as `from startup import *`.

`startup.py`:

```py
# Example modules you always find yourself importing.
import random
import time

# Some function you always create because you need it.
def my_imported_function():
    print("Imported !")
```

Inside Python Debugger Console, use `from startup import *` as mentioned above and you would see all modules and function inside scope, ready for use.

[image: Debug import]

Answer (score 1):

you could just create a new debug configuration (run > edit configurations) and point it to a script in your project (e.g. called `debug.py` that you gitignore). Then when you hit debug it will run that script and drop you into a console.

Personally, I prefer to just launch `ipython` in the embedded terminal than using the debug console. On linux, you can create a bash alias in your `.bashrc` such as `alias debug_myproject=PYTHONSTARTUP=$HOME/myproject/debug.py ipython`. Then calling `debug_myproject` will run that script and drop you into an ipython console.